# C# want to use Task Parallel Library for multiple files

Tags: c#

i want to transfer multiple files but i have used backgroundworker for that. but it can handle only one file. i have heard about Task Parallel Library. so how can use that in my code. or any other better approach to do it?
here is my code...

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Sender2
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtSelectFilePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            String path1=txtSelectFilePath.Text;
            files_list.Items.Add(path1);
            files_list.View = View.List;

        }
    }

    private void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TransferService2.TransferService2Client client = new TransferService2.TransferService2Client();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in files_list.Items)
        {
            TransferService2.File file = client.DownloadDocument(item.Text);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(item.Text);

        } 
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        TransferService2.TransferService2Client client = new TransferService2.TransferService2Client(); 
        string newpath = (string)e.Argument;
            TransferService2.File file = client.DownloadDocument(newpath);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\DownloadedFiles\" + file.Name, FileMode.Create); 
            int pos = 0;
            int length = 128;
            while (pos < file.Content.Length)
            {
                if (length > (file.Content.Length - pos))
                {
                    length = file.Content.Length - pos;
                }
                fs.Write(file.Content, pos, length); 
                int progress_percentage = (int)(((double)pos / (double)file.Content.Length) * 100)+1;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress_percentage);


                pos = pos + length;
            }


    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label_percent.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString()+"%";

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Successful");
    }

}
}
```

TransferService2.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace TransferService2
{

public class TransferService2 : ITransferService2
{

    public File DownloadDocument(String filepath)
    {
        File file = new File();
        String path = filepath;
        byte[] buffer;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        try
        {
            int length = (int)fs.Length;
            buffer = new byte[length];
            int count;
            int sum = 0;
            while((count=fs.Read(buffer,sum,length-sum))>0)
            {
                sum = sum + count;
            }
                        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
        file.Content = buffer;

        file.Name = Path.GetFileName(path);
        return file;
    }
}
}
```

ITransferService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace TransferService2
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "ITransferService2" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITransferService2
{
    [OperationContract]
    File DownloadDocument(String filepath);
}

[DataContract]
public class File
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

}
}
```

Thanx a lot in advance.........

Comment: @Steve i want to use task parallel library for multiple files. ihv used backgroundworker

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. Just replace your `foreach` with `Parallel.ForEach` and set the collection and current item - you can also set the limit of threads you use (how many run at a time) using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, etc. It's pretty flexible.

More documentation here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a sample:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files_list.Items, (item) =>
        {
            TransferService2.File file = client.DownloadDocument(item.Text);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(item.Text);

        });
```

Comment: sir ty for ur quick rpl. means i can use backgroundworker? no need to remove that?

Comment: @ShankyRedkar Test it and see. If it doesn't work it's fairly simple to extract that logic into another class.

Comment: sir, i tried this but error is coming-  This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently.

Comment: @ShankyRedkar then extract that logic. You can extract it to a class and spin up multiple threads for that operation.